# Replace CRLF in Notepad++ using regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to remove CRLFs before a selected word [`[orange]`] and can use `\r\n` [CR=`\r`, LF=`\n`], but the number of CRLFs available before `[orange]` is unknown.

Is there any regex available that I can use to remove all CRLFs before `[orange]` using Notepad++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `*` to look for zero or more occurrences of the previous object

```
(\r\n)*\[orange\]
```

For 1 or more instances use `+` instead of `*`

```
(\r\n)+\[orange\]
```

`[` and `]` are special characters denoting character class so they must be escaped when looking for the literal square brackets